# Adding Apache commons IO to my project

Tags: java, apache, jar, io

**Hello there,**

I've added the **'Apache commons IO'** jar to my project, in a folder called libs.
**Eclipse** does not underline classes anymore from the Apache commons jar, which makes me think it is correctly linked.

But whenever I export my jar, and run it, i'm getting a **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException**.
How can i fix this error?

Additional info:
    - **Not** exporting as **runnable** jar, since this is a plugin for something.
    - I made sure that the jar is inside the exported jar (Opened with WinRAR)

Thanks alot for helping, i've spend over 2 hours searching on the interwebs now!

Comment: You can't put a jar inside a jar... You'll need to reference the commons jar in the MANIFEST or use the `-classpath` option.

Comment: run your project by: `java -cp lib/common-io.jar;bin/classes my.mainclass.Main`

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup I've always put my jdbc jar inside of my jar, which just worked?

Comment: @ajozwik I'm not running the jar myself, since it is a plugin.

Comment: I believe you can get the jar 'repackaged' inside a new jar. Not sure of the procedure however.

Answer (score 0):

Create a manifest file named Manifest.mf and make sure it gets included in your jar file. You can do that at the command line or include it as part of your build. I've used ant in the past to copy the file for me into the jar.

The file should contain entries like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.myproject.MyMainClass
Class-Path: commons-io.jar
```

If that file is packed into your jar file in the META-INF folder, then you should be okay to run it outside of Eclipse. One thing I did to learn this myself was to package a runnable jar with Eclipse that contained everything, and then compared the jar to my own to see the difference. You can also print your classpath out in your code and see the difference between what Eclipse uses and what your program uses when you run it yourself.